# Firefox browser disable safe mode

Tags: firefox, browser, kiosk-mode

I am using Windows 7 and I've been playing with the Firefox browser for a while.
I want to create a kiosk app using it, I installed a plugin for that, but the problem is that when I start the Firefox app, if I press Shift, it enters safe mode.

I read some guides on Google that tell me to edit `chrome/browser.jar` but I have no such file in my Firefox folder.

I need some help for disabling the feature that lets me enter safe mode by pressing Shift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot really disable safe mode by editing text files, the handling of the Shift key is inside [compiled code](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c20d415ef1b5/toolkit/xre/nsAppRunner.cpp#l3068). You can however disable the dialog that pops up by removing this code from [`components/nsBrowserGlue.js`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c20d415ef1b5/browser/components/nsBrowserGlue.js#l309):

```
// check if we're in safe mode
if (Services.appinfo.inSafeMode) {
  Services.ww.openWindow(null, "chrome://browser/content/safeMode.xul", 
                         "_blank", "chrome,centerscreen,modal,resizable=no", null);
}
```

You can also leave extensions enabled in safe mode. For that you will have to also edit [`modules/XPIProvider.jsm`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c20d415ef1b5/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/XPIProvider.jsm#l7768) and remove all occurrences of code like:

```
if (Services.appinfo.inSafeMode)
  return false;
```

Both files can be found inside the `onmi.ja` archive in the Firefox directory.

That said, the proper solution to this problem would be running your own application on top of [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) which would allow you to design your own user interface for kiosk mode. Sadly, Open Kiosk (which is probably what you are using) is ancient and predates XULRunner.

Comment: Im using R-KIOSK addon . So I should get the FIREFOX SOURCE CODES, edit "components/nsBrowserGlue.js", compile them and I would have my copy without SAFE MODE ?

Comment: Please [stop abusing the shift key](http://www.kassj.com/netiquette/netiquette.html#1). You can change the files inside `omni.ja`, it is a regular ZIP archive - no need to recompile Firefox for that.

Comment: thanks for telling me about the ZIP fact, i managed to extract it and im editing the files you mentioned.

Comment: so I changed omni.ja to omni.zip , unpacked, edited the files above , repacked correctly, changed filename to .ja , then when I try to run my firefox copy , i can disable the addons and I can start in SAFE MODE by abusing SHIFT KEY - it's like I did no changes

Comment: @nevergone: You should use [`-purgecaches` command line flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_command_flags).

Comment: I know I'm resurrecting the dead, but it looks like this solution no longer works.  After following all of the above comments, firefox still starts in safe mode.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to disable Firefox session restore and safe mode tweaking these two preferences:

```
browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash  => false
toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes     => -1
```

Comment: This does not prevent you from entering savemode using the shift key.

Comment: Yes, you're right, not the answer to the exact question made. I hope it's still useful for cases where the problem is cumulative power failures.